# JQuery ajax not running, suspected url issue

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, database, post

I am trying to post my record into database by using ajax. I can see there is some error in network tab under inspect. I tried many way of assigning the **url** value, unfortunately, I am failed to figure out. Is anyone can help?

I will show some of my code below.

*this is one of my control, they are duplicated*

```
<li style="text-align:left">
<asp:Label runat="server" >Sex : </asp:Label>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSex" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
 </li>
```

*this is my button*

`<button class="btnSubmit" type="submit" > Submit</button>`

*Below is my javascript to insert data into database*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
      
        e.preventDefault();
        var firstName = document.getElementById('<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('<%=txtSecondName.ClientID%>').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('<%=txtAge.ClientID%>').value;
        var sex = getSelectedSexValue();
        var title = document.getElementById('<%=txtTitle.ClientID%>').value;

    try{

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@(Url.Action("InsertStatement","Home"))',
            datatype: "json",
            //contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                firstName: firstName, secName: lastName,
                age: age, sex: sex, title: title
            }),
            type: 'post',
            success: function (json) {

            },

            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });

    }catch(e){
                    alert(e.message);
             }


    });
    });`
```

*Below is my code to under controller*

```
public JsonResult InsertStatement(string firstName, string secName, int age, string sex, string title)
    {



        try
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
            con.Open();

            string sqlStatement = "insert into Employee values ( '" + firstName + "', '" + secName + "', '" + age + "', '" + sex + "', '" + title + "' )";
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Failure", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }
```

I found that there is an error under network tab
**[Error please refer to this image]**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxb5c.png)

Thank you for reading my question and would be highly appreciated if I can get some ideas from here. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of "error" are you facing? Is there any error message you can share?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged with [tag:database], but does not contain any such code?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the messy format here as I am not really familiar with the editor. I am trying my best to edit as clear as I can.

Comment: the error can be found here ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxb5c.png

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you are facing any error, add that error in text form. Also, you haven't shared any debugging attempts yet

Comment: Also, even if I don't recognize which server-side language you are using, to me that code looks vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a  look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: I am eventually tried to catch error during the code execution, unfortunately, it didn't catch within try catch box. the code is jump to the end of the box when it hit line(ajax) when I tried to debug it. And end up I found an error generated under the network tabs. It seen something wrong with my url part on jquery.

Comment: "And end up I found an error generated under the network tabs" - what does that mean? Can you share the error you are facing, along with your attempts to resolve it? Is this an error caused by the AJAX request? Then please check whether that request is sent as expected by the browser, whether it reaches the server as expected, whether the server is able to handle it properly

Comment: Hi, it's just work after I changed the url format from 

url: '@(Url.Action("InsertStatement","Home"))',

to 

  url: "/Home/InsertStatement"